# document.querySelector().getAttribute() didn't get fresh content meta name

Tags: javascript, jquery, codeigniter

I tried to implement codeigniter with `$config['csrf_regenerate'] = TRUE`;

I create code with combining javascript XMLHttpRequest & Jquery $.ajaxPrefilter.

I make a function for getting new `csrf_hash` from Codeigniter and append to meta name on HTML head.

At first request everything seems working. 
But next request a got message 403 Forbidden because ajax send an old csrf hash.

Please fix my code.

I want before sending a POST request, ajax get new csrf hash form meta name on HTML head.

Sorry for my bad English.

Best Regards,

This is my code

```
$.ajaxPrefilter(function( options, originalOptions, jqXHR ) 
{
    get_csrf_hash(callback =>  document.querySelector('meta[name="csrf_hash"]').setAttribute("content", callback) ); // It Work!!.. Get new csrf_hash and update content meta name.

    if (options.type.toLowerCase() === "post") 
    {
        options.data = $.param($.extend(originalOptions.data, { csrf_simpeg_v2 : document.querySelector('meta[name="csrf_hash"]').getAttribute("content")})); // Not Work didn't send fresh csrf hash
    }

    var originalSuccess = options.success;

    options.success = function(data) 
    {
        if (originalSuccess != null) 
        {
            originalSuccess(data);
        }
    }

    var originalError = options.error;

    options.error = function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) 
    {
        console.log(jqXHR.status + ' ' + jqXHR.statusText);

        if(jqXHR.status == 401 || jqXHR.status == 403)
        {
            alert(jqXHR.status + ' ' + jqXHR.statusText);
        }
        else
        {
            if(originalError != null) 
            {
                originalError();
            }
        }   
    };
});

function get_csrf_hash(callback)
{
    var url = baseURL + 'login/get_csrf_token';

    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();


    xhr.onreadystatechange = function() 
    {
        if (xhr.readyState == XMLHttpRequest.DONE) 
        {
            console.log(xhr.responseText);
            return callback(xhr.responseText);
        }

    }

    xhr.open('GET', url, true);
    xhr.send(null);
}

$(function () {


});
```

Answer (score 0):

`get_csrf_hash` is an asynchronous function, meaning that the JavaScript runtime will not wait for it to finish its task before moving on to executing the next lines. You need to put all the code that depends on the first AJAX request inside the callback:

```
$.ajaxPrefilter(function(options, originalOptions, jqXHR) {
  get_csrf_hash(callback => {
    document.querySelector('meta[name="csrf_hash"]').setAttribute('content', callback);

    if (options.type.toLowerCase() === 'post') {
      options.data = $.param(
        $.extend(originalOptions.data, {
          csrf_simpeg_v2: document.querySelector('meta[name="csrf_hash"]').getAttribute('content')
        })
      );
    }

    var originalSuccess = options.success;

    options.success = function(data) {
      if (originalSuccess != null) {
        originalSuccess(data);
      }
    };

    var originalError = options.error;

    options.error = function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
      console.log(jqXHR.status + ' ' + jqXHR.statusText);

      if (jqXHR.status == 401 || jqXHR.status == 403) {
        alert(jqXHR.status + ' ' + jqXHR.statusText);
      } else {
        if (originalError != null) {
          originalError();
        }
      }
    };
  });
});
```

You should look into the [Fetch API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API) and [Promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Using_promises). They will greatly simplify writing code like this. Here is the `get_csrf_hash` re-written using those tools:

```
function get_csrf_hash(callback) {
  fetch('login/get_csrf_token')
    .then(res => res.text())
    .then(text => callback(text));
}
```

Comment: not work.. ajax send an old `csrf hash` form `<meta name>` tag